# How to pass JSON response in PHP to Javascript

Tags: javascript, php, json, stdclass

I have problems passing a JSON request from PHP to Javascript. I am sending a request to my Flask RESTful API and I'm recieving a JSON reponse (I believe).
**PHP:**

```
$urlContents = file_get_contents("http://192.168.2.201:5000/dataprovider", false, $context);
$travelArray = json_decode($urlContents);
```

My Object looks like this:

```
stdClass Object
(
    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [var1] => 
            [var2] => 
            [var3] => 763
            [var4] => 6:22:30
            [var5] => München
            [var6] => 58
            [var7] => Bremen
            [var8] => 239
        )

    [2] => stdClass Object
        (
            [var1] => 
            [var2] => 
            [var3] => 145
            [var4] => 3:12:23
            [var5] => München
            [var6] => 583
            [var7] => Bremen
            [var8] => 9
        )
)
```

**JavaScript**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
            var response = JSON.parse('<?php echo $travelArray; ?>');
            if (response != null) {
                console.log(response);
            } else {
                console.log("test");
            }
        
</script>
```

When I press F12 and look into *sources* it says:

```
var response = JSON.parse('<br />
<b>Recoverable fatal error</b>:  Object of class stdClass could not be converted to string in <b>/var/www/html/greenTravelWizard.php</b> on line <b>83</b><br />
```

I have tried several things like using $urlContents instead of $travelArray in the JavaScript part ([1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tujy3.png), but I haven't figured out how to correctly pass the JSON to a correct JavaScript format.

Also when I haven't send the request via the form yet I get

**Notice**: Undefined variable: context in **/var/www/html/greenTravelWizard.php** on line **83**
 
 **Warning**: file_get_contents(192.168.2.201:5000/dataprovider): failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.0 405 METHOD NOT ALLOWED in **/var/www/html/greenTravelWizard.php** on line **83**

Comment: Apart from the `decode` bug, it's not recommended to generate PHP inside javascript code. A more standard workflow would be to save your php file as `data.php` and then get the results in javascript using `fetch("data.php")`.

Comment: try this : 
            var response = JSON.parse('<?php echo json_encode($travelArray); ?>');

Comment: If you receive JSON, and want to pass than on to the client _as JSON_ – then why are you _decoding_ the JSON on the server side?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not decode it unless you encode it before echoing

You can likely just do

```
var response = <?php echo $file_get_contents("http://192.168.2.201:5000/dataprovider", false, $context); ?>;
```

If you have written a proxy, then you just need to do

```
<?php
header("content-type: application/json"); 
echo file_get_contents("http://192.168.2.201:5000/dataprovider", false, $context);
?>
```

and then use `fetch`  to get it from your server

Comment: The first option works just fine! Thanks! But do you have an idea how to fix the errors I get when I haven't send the request via the form yet? <br />
<b>Notice</b>:  Undefined variable: context in <b>/var/www/html/greenTravelWizard.php</b> on line <b>83</b><br />
<br />
<b>Warning</b>:  file_get_contents(http://192.168.2.201:5000/dataprovider): failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.0 405 METHOD NOT ALLOWED
 in <b>/var/www/html/greenTravelWizard.php</b> on line <b>83</b><br />

Comment: Maybe they expect a POST and not a GET